# Qt, offset when restore geometry

Tags: c++, qt, offset, qdialog

With Qt 5.11, I have this code to save end restore geometry of a QDialog subclass :

```
    class HlgRunoffEditorDialog:public QDialog
    {
        some code
    }
    void HlgRunoffEditorDialog::show()
    {
        if (isVisible())
            return;
    
        ReosSettings settings;
        restoreGeometry(settings.value(QStringLiteral("RunoffEditorDialog/geometry")).toByteArray());
        ui->splitter->restoreState(settings.value(QStringLiteral("RunoffEditorDialog/splitter/geometry")).toByteArray());
    
        QDialog::show();
    
    }


void HlgRunoffEditorDialog::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    updateSettings();
    QDialog::closeEvent(event);
}

void HlgRunoffEditorDialog::updateSettings()
{
    ReosSettings settings;
    settings.setValue(QStringLiteral("RunoffEditorDialog/geometry"),saveGeometry());
    settings.setValue(QStringLiteral("RunoffEditorDialog/splitter/geometry"),ui->splitter->saveState());
}
```

The problem is when the show() method is called, the windows has an offset with the position before the close event. A picture is more explicit than text :

[image]

The red line is the position before the close event.

It seems like the new position is set the top left point of the widget excluding the windows frame before close event is set on the the top left point of the widget including the windows frame after show() method id called.

Any idea ?

**Edit 1**

This offset above is on Windows. When I run on Linux KDE, it seems like the offset is in the other direction ....

**Edit 2 :**

This offset appear anly when the QDialog is close with the cross on the top right. When the QDialog is closed with the close button (connect to the close() slot), the offset is not here ...

Answer (score 0):

For correct resoring visibility states of widgets (as windows) you must follow this call order:

```
// 1) show the widget
widget->show();

// 2) set status bar visibility (if exists)
//widget->statusBar->setVisible(booleanValueFromSettings);

// 3) set margins (if use it)
//widget->setContentsMargins(a, b, c, d);

// 4) geometry
widget->restoreGeometry(byteArrayFromSettings);

// 5) state (can be use it and for you splitter)
widget->restoreState(byteArrayFromSettings);
```

Comment: If i put the show() method before restoring the geometry, the offset is still here ...

Comment: @vcloarec remove old settings file from filesystem. And before show you can set defaults (e.g. min w/h)

Answer (score 0):

I remember a project where I had to calculate a bit, something like this:

```
QRect ng = w->normalGeometry();
QRect frame = w->frameGeometry();
ng.adjust(-frame.x(), -frame.y(), -frame.x(), -frame.y());
```

and saving the latter values

Comment: And ng.adjust(frame.x(), frame.y(), frame.x(), frame.y()) for X11 on linux ??? ))